# Android In-App Purchasing - is there a way to distribute them for free?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I've been developing Android apps for a few years now with a ad-based revenue model. On top of that, I would also allow users to purchase a separate license that would remove advertising. The license was distributed as a separate app. The main app would check to see if the license was installed, and it would display ads according to whether or not it was there.

I'm finally getting around to replacing this system with Android's in-app purchasing system. The problem that I'm encountering though is how to handle the cases where people have already purchased the older license. I don't want those specific users to have to pay again. From all the research that I've been doing, it looks like the only way that I could do this is by providing a promo-code on an ad-hoc basis.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I would love to find an automated way of providing them with a free version of this in-app purchase if (and only if) they had already bought the old license (which will be removed from Google Play).